# How to loop through array of images in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an Image carousel that contains three images. I have next and previous buttons to click through the array of images, but I would like it to go back to the first image when clicking 'next' on the last image in the array (and to the last one when clicking 'previous' on the first image). Is there a way I can use a loop to make this work?

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
var currentImg = 0;

document.querySelector('.carousel>img').src = 'images/' + images[0];

document.querySelector('.carousel').addEventListener('click', function (evt){
var target = evt.target;
if (target.classList.contains('control')) {

    if (target.classList.contains('next')) {
    //move to the next index in the array 
        currentImg += 1;

    } else if (target.classList.contains('prev')){
    // move to the previous index in the array
        currentImg -= 1;
    } 
    // display the new current image
    document.querySelector('.carousel>img').src = 'images/'
        + images[currentImg];
    }
});
```

I was able to do the following and it did what I wanted:

```
    if (target.classList.contains('next')) {
       if(currentImg==2){
           currentImg=0
      } else {
        currentImg += 1;
      }

    } else if (target.classList.contains('prev')){
       if(currentimg==0){
           currentimg=2
      } else { 
        currentImg -= 1;
    }
```

Thank you for all the other suggestions I will look into those as well!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What would help would be some HTML code... it would just be easier for us users to answer your question :).

Comment: The question is perfectly answerable without the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to go both ways (+ and -), consider:

```
var fac = target.classList.contains('next')? 1 : -1;
currentImage = (currentImage + fac + images.length) % images.length;
```

so if *currentImage* reaches *images.length* it wraps to the first image and if it goes to -1, it "wraps" to *imaages.length - 1*, i.e. the last image.

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code after you've either incremented or decremented **currentImg** and you should be fine:

```
if (currentImg < 0) { 
  currentImg = images.length - 1;
} else if (currentImg >= images.length) {
  currentImg = 0;
}
```

This checks to see if **currentImg** has "escaped" the **images** array boundaries.

Comment: or could use  **ternary operator** here.

Answer (score 0):

Next:

```
++currentImg % 3
```

Prev:

```
--currentImg % 3
```

If needed replace 3 with whatever the size of the Array.

Comment: Or use images.length in place of 3 to make you code future proof.

Comment: @RobG I think javascript and php replace negative indexes with length-index , or count from other end.

Comment: @ArifBurhan nope, they don't.

Comment: @ArifBurhan— *currentImage* is just a number, it has no special properties.

Comment: @RobG also true in ruby :    **https://h3manth.com/new/blog/2013/negative-array-index-in-javascript/**

Comment: The full code would be   ** image[currentImage] ** you're right, currentImage is just an integer index.

Comment: @ArifBurhan—yes, and some methods do accept -ve indexes (e.g. *Array.prototype.slice*), but Arrays are essentially Objects with a special *length* property, so property access behaves just like an Object and the value is treated literally, it's not a getter. It would be handy if it was though.×An error occurred during comment submission×An error occurred during comment submission×An error occurred during comment submission